# Python :how to merge data using for column with partial values pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

have two  df's  with values :

how to partially merge dataframe considering UPPERCASE letters only in df (column = county) with df1

df:

```
name      age   county

mark      22    York_USA_TXS
stuart    23    kysjk_USA
lewis     22    Monty_KYSJK
```

df1 :

```
pin   county

2225    USA
2225    USA
2226    KYSJK
```

expected output:

```
name      age   county            pin

mark      22    York_USA_TXS      2225
stuart    23    kysjk_USA         2225
lewis     22    Monty_KYSJK       2226
```

Comment: Why is df first row merged with the df1 row with pin = 2225? Based on your description you should compare USA_TXS with USA.

Comment: i was trying to do a partial merge for USA which is in caps

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the counties always follow the same pattern in `df1` (i.e. `{something_COUNTY_...}`, then a possible solution is:

```
merged = pandas.merge(df1[['name', 'age']], 
         df2, 
         left_on=df1.county.apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[1]), 
         right_on=df2.county).drop_duplicates()
merged[['name', 'age', 'county', 'pin']]
```

The "key" thing here is `df1.county.apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[1])`, where you essentially apply a function to the column `county` to extract the second element, after you split by `_`. Note that this works for the data you gave us, but you might need to tweak the function for your needs (for example if what you *actually* want to merge on is `USA_TXS` rather than `USA`).

Answer (score 1):

With `series.str.extract`:

```
s = df['county'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(set(df1['county']))})",expand=False)
df['pin'] = s.map(dict(df1[['county','pin']].drop_duplicates().to_numpy()))
```

---

```
print(df)

     name  age        county   pin
0    mark   22  York_USA_TXS  2225
1  stuart   23     kysjk_USA  2225
2   lewis   22   Monty_KYSJK  2226
```